# Use for_each to create multiple disks and their snapshots using a list input

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am writing TF code to create multiple disks in GCP. The aim is to have dry code and have a list as an input.

My var `app_disks` has the following definition

```
variable "app_disks" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    size = number
  }))
}
```

And in my main.tf, im using the variable like this

```
  app_disks = [
    {
      name = loki
      size = 200
    },
    {
      name = repo
      size = 100
    }
  ]
```

And in my module, my disk.tf looks like this

```
locals {
  app_disk_map = {
    for disk in var.app_disks : "${disk.name}" => disk
  }
}

resource "google_compute_resource_policy" "app_disk_backup" {
  for_each = local.app_disk_map

  name   = "${each.value.name}-backup"

  snapshot_schedule_policy {
    schedule {
      hourly_schedule {
        hours_in_cycle = 8
        start_time     = "04:00"
      }
    }
    retention_policy {
      max_retention_days    = 14
      on_source_disk_delete = "APPLY_RETENTION_POLICY"
    }
  }
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "app_disk" {
  for_each = local.app_disk_map

  provider = google-beta

  name = each.value.name
  zone = "${var.region}-a"
  size = each.value.size

  resource_policies = [each.google_compute_resource_policy.app_disk_backup[${each.value.name}-backup].self_link]
}
```

What im not sure about it how to link the `resource_policies` of the disk to its relevant `google_compute_resource_policy"`.

Ive tried combinations like

```
each.google_compute_resource_policy.app_disk_backup[${each.value.name}-backup].self_link

each.google_compute_resource_policy.app_disk_backup."${each.value.name}-backup".self_link
```

But none seem to be working

Comment: can you share the plan error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure if I get the problem right (as an error output is missing), but from what I understood you want to have the following reference: `google_compute_resource_policy.app_disk_backup[each.key].self_link` so the resource would look something like:

```
resource "google_compute_disk" "app_disk" {
  for_each = local.app_disk_map

....

  resource_policies = [google_compute_resource_policy.app_disk_backup[each.key].self_link]
}
```

this will reference the same key that was used to create the dependent resource and create a 1:1 mapping between dependencies.